# trying to verify hashed password and validate login pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hash

Hello I am trying to use pdo to return hashed passwords from database and allow users to login while their password is being protected. I have built a sign up page which hashes the password. I am now trying to dehash this. I think I am close but this has been many days stuck in the same place, I was hoping someone could help me finalise my code?

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in /var/www/html/login.php:54\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/login.php on line 54, referer: http://172.16.62.211/login.php

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

  $q = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
  $query = $q->execute(array(
        $username));
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $count = $q->rowCount();
  if ($count == 1 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){   
      $hash_pwd = $count['password'];
      $hash = password_verify($password, $hash_pwd);

  if ($hash_pwd == 0) {
      header("location: login.php?error=empty");
  }

  else {
    $q = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? && password = $hash_pwd');
     $query = $q->execute(array(
        $username,
        $password));

    $count = $q->rowCount();
       if($count == 1){
          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
          header("location: index.php");
          return;
       } else {
        echo '<p class="error-message3">'.'<br>'.'<br>'."You have ented an incorrecct login!<br>Please try  again.".'</p>';
  }}}}
  ?>
```

Comment: *"I am now trying to dehash this."* - what do you mean by that exactly? and which one is line 54?

Comment: You also only have 1 placeholder in the query but using 2 in the array for `$q = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? && password = $hash_pwd');`. which is also failing for another reason.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am trying to dehash a hashed password in my database to enable login.

Comment: A: You can't. Hashes are just that; hashed (one way). One can't make a beef come out looking like one after it's all been cut up ;-)

Comment: You don't *dehash* anything, you just verify. Is the database column you're storing the passwords in bigger than 60 characters?

Comment: The purpose of hashing is that it can't be reversed...

Comment: Please read up on the usage of [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Sorry my terminology isnt the best, I am a frontend developer training to learn database side. Yes @JayBlanchard the chracters are set to 100. thanks

Comment: Btw; I find that you have too many unclosed questions.

Comment: On a side note, don't use `SELECT *` , specify only the columns you need instead of returning everything, as time goes on you might add new columns to the tables being queried, adding extra overhead unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You WONT and you CANT 'dehash' the password from your database.

The normal routine consists basically [of converting the password inserted by the user to your security logic encrypt and compare with the password stored in your db (hashed too)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the two values must be equal to validate.

Dehash a password is, if the hash was done correctly, in some ways kind of impossible, not to point the security flaw about your idea.

```
if ($count == 1 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){   
      $hash_pwd = $count['password'];
      $hash = password_verify($password, $hash_pwd);
      if ($hash === false) {
          header("location: login.php?error=empty");
      } else {

              $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
              header("location: index.php");
              return;
           } 
    } else {
            echo '<p class="error-message3">'.'<br>'.'<br>'."You have ented an incorrecct login!<br>Please try  again.".'</p>';
      }
```

PS: Indent better your code and notes that some routines you are repeating the checking, in the password_verify you already checked like a said above.

Comment: Okay guys, sorry i understand I cannot dehash, but How do I verify the password?

Comment: You see if `password_verify()` returned true @diced.pinapple

Comment: I already said in the question: you convert the password inserted by the user in the login moment and compares in your database

Comment: I have editied my code since then quite a bit.

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $username = $_POST['username'];
           $password = $_POST['password'];
              $q = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
              $result = $q->execute(array($username));
         
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
               if ($q->rowCount() > 0){
                   $result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                   $hash_pwd = $result['password'];
                   $hash = password_verify($password, $hash_pwd);

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the usage of [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), it takes *raw* (unhashed) version of the password **and** the *hashed* version (from your database) and returns respectively true/false.

```
<?php
if (password_verify($raw, $hash)) {

}
?>
```

You don't need to compare it in your query, just retrieve the password from by the username provided (if the username is valid) and then verify.

Comment: Down-voter, care to explain? If there is something wrong in my answer, do say. Don't just vote and leave.